# Ember.js view computed property is not passed to action handler

Tags: action, ember.js

I've got ember (1.0.0-pre2) view which has a form and a button. The form is bound to a view class which allows populating form inputs and gathering entered values.
Now on button click I want to create a dto object from the form values and send it to controller.
The button html is as follows

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" data-icon="plus" {{action addReport view.report target="controller"}} />
```

The view code is

```
ContentView: baseView.extend({
    task: null, //initialized when form is filled in
    report: function () {
        var task = this.get('task');
        if (task == null)
            return null;

        return reportModel.create({
            taskId: task.id
        });
    }.property()
})
```

The controller code is

```
DayController: ember.Controller.extend({
    addReport: function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.context);
    }
})
```

When I run the code, the event context is null. When I look in the debugger, the `report` computed property executed only once, when the view is rendered. On button click the computed property is not evaluated - controller method is invoked right away.

Very similar construction works fine in the same application but for different view and the method is in the router, not controller:

```
<a href="#" {{action changeDate view.prevDate href=true}}>Prev</a>
```

view:

```
HeaderView: baseView.extend({
    prevDate: function () {
        return addDays(this.get('_dataSource').date, -1);
    }.property()
})
```

What is wrong with the button, why it doesn't work as opposed to the link?

Comment: Before I attempt to answer I just want to verify something: you have `var task = this.get('task')` in the report property function-- that means `task` is a property on `ContentView` in your code but just omitted from the example?

Comment: Yes, `task` is the property of the ContentView. I updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some debugging I found out the core misconception.

The context of the action evaluated by the handlebars `action` helper, which executed only when rendered. This was the reason why the other view worked - it didn't require the data provided by user in the current view, all necessary information was ready before the view displayed.

So the `context` field must be provided before the view is rendered ant this is not relevant for my scenario. I have to resort to the workaround in controller

```
DayController: ember.Controller.extend({
    addReport: function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.view.get('report'));
    }
})
```

Too bad, I hoped I could go without creating additional dependencies from controller to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your specific problem but computed properties should specify dependencies.  For example,

```
}.property('task')
```

Ember will cache computed properties.  The dependency allows Ember to know when the cache property has been invalidated.

Comment: No, adding dependency didn't help. But as far as I understand, by default if no caching and dependencies specified, the property is evaluated on each access?